# The specified password for user account 'root' is not valid, or failed to connect to database server

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, iis-8, web-platform-installer

I am getting this error while installing WordPress using Windows platform installer 5.0 on a Windows Server 2012R2.

Currently I have a php site with mySQL on that server which is running fine,
PHP, MYSQL was already installed as part of setting up that site couple of months ago.

MySQL .NET Connector  was already installed, I have repair it(http://dancerscode.com/blog/the-annoying-mysql-web-platform-installer-bug/) using latest installer as well. Installed WebMatrix3 which was mentioned in same article but No luck.

I have made sure that mySQL password is correct by logging in using command line.

Any idea?
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally found the solution.

I had Connector/Net 6.9.9 installed

I uninstalled it and then Installed Connector/Net 6.4.6

Old version of Connector can be downloaded here(https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/)

Comment: Tried but still same error, what could be further steps to resolve this??

Comment: The solution above is not working, post installing older or latest connectors still same error.

Comment: @KeshavdasM I achived the above on Windows Server 2012 R2 if its not working for you could this be down to the fact you are using a different version of windows OS?

Comment: uninstall mySql Server and reinstall it. this is how I resolved my problem.