# the specified password for user account root is not valid or failed

Tags: wordpress, iis, web-platform-installer

I have Visual Studio 2015 + SQL Server 2014 installed on my PC. Now i'm trying to install WordPress through WEB PLATFORM INSTALLER 5.1. I'm following the thread 
https://codex.wordpress.org/Installing_on_Microsoft_IIS
but while installing it gives the error 
[the specified password for user account root is not valid or failed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q7jS6.png)

is there anything conflicting with installation?

Comment: There is no way for us to troubleshoot this issue without looking at your settings.  This question is too broad to answer.

Comment: which type of settings? this installation only ask for root password which is, whatever we set, it always give error!

Answer (score 0):

There is a similar thread here with the answer [The specified password for user account 'root' is not valid, or failed to connect to database server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43741440/the-specified-password-for-user-account-root-is-not-valid-or-failed-to-connec)

(an older version of the .net connector needing to be installed, and the newer one removed)

Hope this helps