# Web Platform installer issue of installing wordpress wrong password error

Tags: iis, windows-server-2012, web-platform-installer

Starting of with the issue i am facing. I am trying to install wordpress using Microsoft Web Platform Installer 5.1. I am facing the error as pasted in image [image]

I have gone through one of the answers pasted on stack overflow[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43741440/the-specified-password-for-user-account-root-is-not-valid-or-failed-to-connec) but that has not helped me in solving the problem. Password i am using is absolutely correct but i am unable to find solution to the issue. I have spent almost 2 days to solve this issue but cant find any solution. Hope to get one soon. Thanks in advance

Comment: Deleted all the folders :Program files \ MySQL,(86) files \MySQL,Program Data\MySQL,Roaming\MySQL.Uninstall MySQL 5.1. Then reinstall (MySQL connector](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/), MySQL. Finally, Try to install WordPress via web platform installer.remember to disable firewall and anti-virus before the installation. Make sure the password is extra strong.